# Why the disassembly code is not using ebp to obtain the input argument?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, x86, disassembly

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Below `main()` calls the `function(MyArray arg)`.

The `array1` argument is passed through the stack. (**place 1**)

But where does the `[arg]` come from?? (**place 2**)

I thought it should be something like `move   ecx, dowrd ptr [ebp + 8]`.

Is this some kind of Visual Studio friendly display?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

typedef int MyArray[10];


void function (MyArray arg)
{
  printf ("\n[1] = %d\n", arg[1]);
}


int main()
{
  MyArray array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
  printf ("\nMyArray size = %d, array1 size = %d\n", sizeof (MyArray), sizeof (array1));


  function (array1);

  return 0;

}
```

---

```
  function (array1);
00D84DE1  lea         eax,[array1]  
00D84DE4  push        eax ; <=======  place 1. pass "array1" address via stack.
00D84DE5  call        function (0D81352h)  
00D84DEA  add         esp,4
```

---

```
void function (MyArray arg)
{
00A516E0  push        ebp  
00A516E1  mov         ebp,esp  
00A516E3  sub         esp,0C0h  
00A516E9  push        ebx  
00A516EA  push        esi  
00A516EB  push        edi  
00A516EC  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h]  
00A516F2  mov         ecx,30h  
00A516F7  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00A516FC  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
  printf ("\n[1] = %d\n", arg[1]);
00A516FE  mov         eax,4  
00A51703  shl         eax,0  
00A51706  mov         ecx,dword ptr [arg] ;<=== place 2, where does the "[arg]" come from?
00A51709  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+eax]  
00A5170C  push        edx  
00A5170D  push        offset string "\n[1] = %d\n" (0A56B30h)  
00A51712  call        _printf (0A51316h)  
00A51717  add         esp,8  
}
```

### ADD 1 -- 9:59 PM 7/2/2021

The compilation flags:

> /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb"
> /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D
> "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1
> /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug"
> /Fp"Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pch"

The linking flags:

> /OUT:"C:\D\temp\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe"
> /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT
> /PDB:"C:\D\temp\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pdb"
> /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib"
> "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib"
> "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86
> /INCREMENTAL
> /PGD:"C:\D\temp\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pgd"
> /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
> /ManifestFile:"Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe.intermediate.manifest"
> /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

Comment: That assembly code just seems very odd... It's doing a lot of things that just doesn't make any sense. How do you build? With what flags? How do you get the disassembly? If I try it on the compiler explorer [I don't get near the same assembly code generated](https://godbolt.org/z/zGn3r3bYq).

Comment: Also, is the C source code the *complete* code you have? What happens if you add `#include <stdio.h>` at the top? Does that change anything?

Comment: I've tried to recreate this in MSVC 2015, and can't get the same output. It would appear you are compiling this with debugging enabled? I'd recommend NOT doing that, because debug builds are deliberately de-optimised (Often copying variables to known locations after each operation has been performed - primarily so the debugger can keep track of the variables when they are inflight). Release output: https://godbolt.org/z/6ecnK5oG6

Comment: I think the compiler is trying to be helpful by showing you the symbol name rather than the actual code, which is `dword ptr [ebp+8]`.

Comment: Yes, this is some kind of friendly display

Comment: Enable optimizations if you want to analyze the generated code: https://godbolt.org/z/os9sGadxn

Comment: Incidentally setting up a stack frame and hence using `EBP` for accessing parameters is not a requirement - sometimes it's omitted especially for functions with few arguments and no locals.

Comment: @robthebloke I changed the compilation flag to `x86` and `/Od` in your godbolt link. It gives me some similar input. The `arg` is obtained with `DWORD PTR [ebp + 8]`. Only that there's no `0xCC` filling in the stack. (Unfortunately, I don't know how to generate a godbolt link for my result.)

Comment: @smwikipedia: You click the "Share" button in the upper right.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks! I got the link: https://godbolt.org/z/E9fK54K3T

Comment: To get the 0xCC, you need to add /Gz. It's an uninitialised variable check. Attempting to decipher debug code is a fools errand. It's deliberately de-optimised, performing seemingly pointless moves, just so that the debugger is able to reliably determine the value of certain variables at runtime.  As mentioned above, if you want to understand asm, use /O1 (for non-optimised code, without the debug fluff, so you can see the calling conventions in action), or /O2 for an even easier to understand build. /Od will produce a nonsense, that's only useful for the debugger to understand.

Comment: Just compare the convoluted way that eax is handled prior to the printf call when using /Od /GZ (debug == deliberately de-optimised), and the actual non-optimised approach of /O1. You won't learn much from debug builds.